# On a Django site, how to show correct section navigation

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm re-working a Django site and it's divided into sections. Each section has a separate set of navigation. I'm struggling with how best to highlight the correct one.

Initially I started setting a context variable in the view and using that to pick the correct subnav. eg:

```
# views.py
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['subnav'] = 'news'
        return context

# templates/base.html
{% if subnav %}
    <ul>
        {% if subnav == 'news' %}
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        {% elif subnav == 'sport' %}
            <!-- etc -->
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

That works fine... but only if every page has a view. All the [Flatpages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/) don't, for example.

I'm going round and round with context processors and template tags and nothing seems satisfactory. Any ideas?

(One obvious way would be to put each bit of subnav HTML in separate templates and extend from those for separate pages... but I already use template inheritance for different sorts of layouts, and adding the dimension of section would complicate matters hugely.)

Comment: Have you looked into matching on `request.path`?

Comment: I could, with regular expressions... although even then there will be a lot of paths that could be matched for each section. Does the template, or a template tag, have access to the URL's name for the currently-viewed page?

Comment: I don't think you could access the `name` parameter of the URL matched and pass it to the template easily (someone please correct me if I'm wrong), but you do have access to `request.path` at the template level.

Comment: Yeah, it just feels a bit wrong to me to be matching URLs in templates, given that all the URLs I use in templates (eg, in `<a href...>`) use named URLs. It seems fragile.

Comment: It is definitely fragile. Perhaps the `{% url %}` template tag could be modified to check for a matching path based on the incoming request and add a css class to the template context for the link. Just thinking outloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out what seems like a reasonable solution.

I made a custom [assignment tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags) that sets the name of the subnavigation for the current page:

```
# templatetags/nav_tags.py

from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.assignment_tag
def get_subnav(request):

    # The names on the right are the names of URLs:
    subnavs = (
        ('news', ('home', 'news_archive', 'news_month_archive')),
        ('sport', ('sport_home', 'sport_archive', 'sport_month_archive')),
        # etc
    )

    url_name = request.resolver_match.url_name

    for subnav, names in subnavs:
        if url_name in names:
            return subnav

    return False
```

Notes:

- This assumes you're using [named URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) in your `urls.py`.
- `request.resolver_match.url_name` is only available since Django 1.5.

Then in the template I can do:

```
{% load nav_tags %}

{% get_subnav request as subnav %}

{% if subnav %}
    <ul>
        {% if subnav == 'news' %}
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        {% elif subnav == 'sport' %}
            <!-- etc -->
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

This has the benefit of reducing the amount of "if request.path=this or request.path=that or request.path=..." in the template itself. And the benefit of not relying on actual URL paths anywhere, which always seems fragile to me -- it's what named URLs are for.

I also made a context processor that puts `url_name` in the template context, as I find it useful to have around, and stops me relying on URL paths in other places.